# How to extract the error message from a GCM json decoded response

Tags: php

I am fairly new with PHP and I'm stuck on this big time.

I am trying to extract the error message "**InvalidRegistration**" in this instance, which appears to be in an array within an array and then filter and act upon it in my PHP server.

Note that the error array may have a greater depth than 1 on multicast messages to multiple regId's.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

***Dumped GCM server response:***

object(stdClass)#3 (5) { ["multicast_id"]=> int(6225919148914620552) ["success"]=> int(0) ["failure"]=> int(1) ["canonical_ids"]=> int(0) ["results"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["error"]=> string(19) "**InvalidRegistration**" } } }

**Send message code:**

```
    $dbf = new push_db_functions();  

    // a row id which contains an intentionally bad regId
    // to trigger the error from 'test' mySql database
    $id = '19'; 

    $result = $dbf->sendMessage($id);

    // dump GCM server response  
    $obj2 = json_decode($result);  
    var_dump($obj2);

   // TODO: (Question Subject)
   // how to extract and test for if('failure' == 1) { ...?
   // and then how to extract 'error' message so I can act upon it appropriately?
```

**Send message helper code:**

```
public function sendMessage($id) {
    $sqlquery = "SELECT regid FROM test WHERE Id = '$id'";
    $results = mysql_query($sqlquery);
    $processed = mysql_fetch_row($results);
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $apiKey = "my api key";
    $message = "Hello World";
    $fields = array('registration_ids' => $processed, 'data' => array( "message" => $message),);
    $headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey, 'Content-Type: application/json');
    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    // execute post
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just grab the error code given, you should be able to use

```
$obj2->results[0]->error;
```

But if you want to do it flexibly, you may wish to do something more along the lines of...

```
$errors = array();

if( !empty($obj2->results) ) {
    foreach( $obj2->results as $result ) {
        $error = $result->error;
        // Do whatever you want with the error here. 
        // In this instance, I'm just putting it into a fancy array
        $errors[] = $error;
    }
}

// $errors = array( [0] => 'InvalidRegistration' );
```

Comment: Also, as a side note, I will have to scald you for using 'obj' and it's variations as variable names. Variable names are precious devices that us coders use to help keep code easy to read, and thus maintainable. One could even go so far as to say they make the code pretty. Even variables '$obj' and '$var' have a purpose, so be nice to yourself and name them accordingly :).

Comment: Thanks for the coding advice too.

Answer (score 1):

Simple decode response in JSON

```
 $data = json_decode($response);
```

The output of this if

```
 
{
    "multicast_id": 5020929399500020011,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "error": "NotRegistered"
    }]
}
```

And now you can easily parse error and result in json.

Hope this will help you guys.